# Moodle Quiz report attempts details

Tags: moodle

I want to make a report for quizzes in moodle:
How do I get:
how many candidate given quiz, how much pass and top ten list for quiz?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of built in quiz reports available. Please check:

https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=13

Hope this helps